# Ansible: Pass command arguments as a list

Tags: ansible

I want to store multiple arguments in a variable as a list.

```
vars:
  my_args:
    - --verbose
    - --quiet
    - --verify
```

Then pass the list as quoted arguments to a command. The most obvious `join`
filter doesn't work as I expected. It produces a single word containing all list elements as opposed to one word per list element:

```
tasks:
  - command: printf '%s\n' "{{ my_args | join(' ') }}"
...
changed: [localhost] => {
"changed": true,
"cmd": [
    "printf",
    "%s\\n",
    " --quiet  --verbose  --verify "
],

STDOUT:

 --quiet  --verbose  --verify
```

How to pass them to a command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To pass a list elements as arguments to a module use either `map('quote') | join(' ')` filters or the `for` loop:

```
tasks:

- name: Pass a list as arguments to a command using filters
  command: executable {{ my_args | map('quote') | join(' ') }}

- name: Pass a list as arguments to a command using for loop
  command: executable {% for arg in my_args %} "{{ arg }}" {% endfor %}
```

*Do not use* quotes with filter, but *do use* them with a loop. Although being slightly longer, the `for` loop gives more possibilities of shaping the output. For example prefixing or suffixing the list item like `"prefix {{ item }} suffix"`, or applying filters to the item or even selectively processing items using `loop.*` [variables](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#for).

The example in question would be:

```
tasks:
  - command: printf '%s\n' {{ my_args | map('quote') | join(' ') }}
  - command: printf '%s\n' {% for arg in my_args %} "{{ arg }}" {% endfor %}
...
changed: [localhost] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": [
        "printf",
        "%s\\n",
        "--quiet",
        "--verbose",
        "--verify"
    ],

STDOUT:

--quiet
--verbose
--verify
```

List elements are not limited to simple strings and can contain some logic:

```
vars:
  my_args:
    - --dir={{ my_dir }}
    - {% if my_option is defined %} --option={{ my_option }} {% endif %}
```

Comment: How about `{{ my_args | join(' ') }}` ?

Comment: If for whatever reason you need to quote arguments then `"{{ my_args | join }}"`will produce a single word i.e. a single argument. The for loop with `"{{ arg }}"` will produce separate words.

Comment: You can apply filters... `{{ mylist | map('quote') | join(' ') }}`

Comment: That doesn't work as you expect. Try `- command: printf '%s\n' "{{ my_args | map('quote') | join(' ') }}"` and compare with `- command: printf '%s\n' {% for arg in my_args %} "{{ arg }}" {% endfor %}`.

Comment: Now, that remark about double quotes was useful. I'll include it in the answer.