# Ansible - run shell command with one or more parameters from vars

Tags: ansible

That title probably isn't the clearest.  I'm trying to use ansible to configure something via shell commands (there's no module for this), in this format:

`dsconf dirname backend index add --index-type arg1 --index-type arg2 --attr attr1 userRoot`

What's tripping me up is that --index-type option - it may be called one or more times with different parameters.

I have the following vars defined:

```
indexes:
  - name: "attr1"
    indextype:
      - "arg1"
  - name: "attr2"
    indextype:
      - "arg1"
      - "arg2"
```

But I can't figure out how to write my task to handle the variable number of parameters for --index-type.  As a simple and obviously wrong example:

```
- command: "dsconf {{ host_name }} backend index add --reindex --index-type {{ item.indextype }} --attr {{ item.name }} userRoot"
  register: index
  with_items:
    - "{{ indexes }}"
```

This results in "--index-type [arg1, arg2]".  I'd need to have it somehow repeat --index-type for each of the arguments, like "--index-type arg1 --index-type arg2".

I've found some good examples ([such as this link](https://chromatichq.com/blog/untangling-ansible-loops)) on how to use nested items and subelements to address this with built-ins, but I can't figure out how to translate that to a shell command.  I also found [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49799595/ansible-pass-command-arguments-as-a-list) that's close, but it's joining the nested items themselves as the arguments, rather than using the nested items as a parameter for the argument and repeating the argument as many times as necessary.

Is there any good way to do this?  I can probably include the full argument and parameter in the subelement list like this and then join like in that second example:

```
  - name: "attr2"
    indextype:
      - "--index-type arg1"
      - "--index-type arg2"
```

but, was hoping for something a bit cleaner.  Would appreciate any ideas.  Or an explanation for why I'm doing this entirely wrong, if that's the case.  :-)  Thanks.

--- EDIT ---

So yeah, refactoring as follows does work:

```
  - name: "attr1"
    parameters:
      - "--index-type arg1"
      - "--index-type arg1"


- command: "dsconf {{ host_name }} backend index add --reindex {{ item.parameters | join(' ') }} --attr {{ item.name }} userRoot"
  register: index
  with_items:
    - "{{ indexes }}"
```

Am still interested in if there's some way to address this as originally asked, but I can certainly work with this approach if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: **"*handle the variable number of parameters for --index-type*"**

A: That's what [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/) is for. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ cmd_part1 }}{{ cmd_part2 }}{{ cmd_part3 }}"
      loop: "{{ indexes }}"
      vars:
        cmd_part1: "dsconf options"
        cmd_part3: " --attr {{ item.name }} userRoot"
        cmd_part2: |-
          {% for i in item.indextype %} --index-type {{ i }}{% endfor %}
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: dsconf options --index-type arg1 --attr attr1 userRoot
  msg: dsconf options --index-type arg1 --index-type arg2 --attr attr2 userRoot
```

See [YAML Block Styles](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#Block).

Comment: Thanks!  Apologies for the tardy reply, but just got a chance to get back to this and your example worked great.  Very helpful, and gives me another tool in my belt so to speak going forward.  Much appreciated!